# Lucene SimpleFacetedSearch Facet count exceeded 2048

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I've stumbled into an issue using Lucene.net in one of my project where i'm using the SimpleFacetedSearch feature to have faceted search.

I get an exception thrown

> Facet count exceeded 2048

I've a 3 columns which I'm faceting as soon as a add another facet I get the exception.

If I remove all the other facets the new facet works.

Drilling down into the source of SimpleFacetedSearch I can see inside the constructor of SimpleFacetedSearch it's checking of the number of facets don't exceed MAX_FACETS which is a constant set to 2048.

```
  foreach (string field in groupByFields)
  {
    ...
    num *= fieldValuesBitSets1.FieldValueBitSetPair.Count;
    if (num > SimpleFacetedSearch.MAX_FACETS)
        throw new Exception("Facet count exceeded " + (object) SimpleFacetedSearch.MAX_FACETS);
    fieldValuesBitSets.Add(fieldValuesBitSets1);
    ...
  }
```

However as it's public I am able to set it like so.

```
SimpleFacetedSearch.MAX_FACETS = int.MaxValue;
```

Does anyone know why it is set to 2048 and if there are issues changing it? I was unable to find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there should't be any issue in changing it. But remember that using `Bitsets`(as done by `SimpleFacetedSearch` internally) is more performant when the search results are big but facet counts don't exceed *some* number. (Say 1000 facets 10M hits)

If you have much more  facets but search results are not big you can iterate on the results(in a collector) and create facets. This way you may get a better performance. (say 100K facets 1000 hits)

So, 2048 may be an optimized number where exceeding it may result in performance loss.

Comment: Do you have any examples on how to build the facets in a collector?

Comment: From [SimpleFacetedSearch](https://cwiki.apache.org/LUCENENET/simple-faceted-search.html)'s wiki page:  http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=zrew4dimoktd6vex&number=1

Comment: I think this is a more up-to-date link for the wiki page: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/LUCENENET/Simple+Faceted+Search

Answer (score 1):

The problem that MAX_FACETS is there to avoid is one of memory usage and performance.
Internally SimpleFS uses bitmaps to record which documents each facet value is used in. There is a bit for each document and each value has a separate bitmap. So if you have a lot of values the amount of memory needed grows quickly especially if you also have a lot of documents. memory = values * documents /8 bytes.

My company has indexes with millions of documents and 10's of thousands of values which would require many GB's of memory.

I've created another implementation which I've called SparseFacetedSearcher. This records the doc IDs for each value. So you only pay for hits not a bits per doc. If you have exactly one value in each document (like a product category) then the break even point is if you have more than 32 values (more than 32 product categories).
In our case the memory usage has dropped to a few 100MB.

Feel free to have a look at https://github.com/Artesian/SparseFacetedSearch